# How to interpolate a set of waypoints?

Tags: qgis-plugins, point, interpolation, fields-attributes, vector-layer

I am trying to interpolate a Vector Layer in order to have as many waypoints as possible. I am doing it with the Interpolation Plugin, but I don't know what to do with the Raster Layer generated (I was expecting as output an other Vector Layer with more waypoints than the original one).

In the figure below you can see what am I trying to iterpolate: 
[image]

So, the layer "test2" has two attributes (one for each route of the map). I don't know if it is relevant, but when I am in the Interpolation Window I am not able to select any "Interpolation Attribute":
[image]

What output format should I choose if I want to obtain a "copy" of test2 but with interpolated waypoints.